# Conditional COUNT and GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Source_Table
    ([Student_ID] varchar(10), [Class_ID] varchar(10), [Sport] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Source_Table
    ([Student_ID], [Class_ID], [Sport])
VALUES
    ('S00001', 'C0123A', 'Football'),
    ('S00002', 'C0123A', 'Football'),
    ('S00003', 'C0123A', 'Football'),
    ('S00004', 'C0123A', 'Football'),
    ('S00005', 'C0111B', 'Basketball'),
    ('S00006', 'C0111B', 'Basketball'),
    ('S00007', 'C0211C', 'Basketball'),
    ('S00008', 'C0100D', 'Soccer'),
    ('S00009', 'C0100D', 'Soccer');
```

and I would like the following output:

The Rule is: For Class_ID having count(Student_ID) >=3, count only once

```
Sport   Count
Basketball  3
Football    **1**
Soccer  2
```

I have tried a GROUP BY Sport and COUNT (CLASS_ID), but unsure of how to implement the rule.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e6a3/3

```
select Sport, Count(Class_Id) from Source_Table
group by Sport
```

The output of what I've tried is:

```
Sport   Count
Basketball  3
Football    **4** when I would like it to be Football **1**
Soccer  2
```

Comment: but football has 4 rows. Why should it be 1?

Comment: the rule is to count it once when class_id has >= 3 students in them

Comment: @DaleBurrell fiddle is for SQL Server. I've removed MySQL tag

Comment: How about basktball and soccer, should they be equal to zero?

Comment: @ibu - basketball is fine as 3 because there are 3 class_id, student_id combinations (even though C0111B repeats, it is fine because it doesn't break the rule of having 3 or more students in it), soccer is fine at 2 because there  are 2 class_id, student_id combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results you want with this query. It uses a subquery to Count the number of students for each Sport/Class_Id combination. In the outer query it sums the Counts, replacing the Count for a class which has 3 or more students with 1:

```
select Sport, SUM(CASE WHEN Count >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE Count END) AS Count
FROM (select Sport, Class_Id, Count(Student_Id) AS Count
      from Source_Table
      group by Sport, Class_Id) s
GROUP BY Sport
```

Output:

```
Sport       Count
Basketball  3
Football    1
Soccer      2
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e6a3/9)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is a `case` expression:

```
select Sport,
       (case when count(*) > 3 then 1 else count(*) end) as cnt
from Source_Table
group by Sport;
```

If you need to count distinct students, then do that:

```
select Sport,
       (case when count(distinct class_id) > 3 then 1 else count(*) end) as cnt
from Source_Table
group by Sport;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I think so too , no need to subquery.

Comment: @BTag this won't give the correct result when a sport has a class which has 3 or more students as well as any other classes. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a406/5

Comment: @Nick, that's right. your solution takes into account the combination of the class and student.

Comment: @Btag . . . I found the question ambiguous on what the limit on "3" was referring to.  The answer is easily adjusted to count distinct students.

Comment: @Gordon, if the number of students within a class is >=3 , that class will only be counted once. Not trying to count students here but classes per sport.

Comment: @BTag . . . Your question is very unclear on what you want to count, but counting the classes is also very easy.

Comment: @Gordon it's also not simply counting the distinct class_id for each sport, but conditionally - if there are 3 or more students in a particular class, we shall only count the class once.